# DHCP Discover ethernet frame check sequence incorrect

Tags: 18.04, ethernet, dhcp, dhclient, checksums

I did apt dist-upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After that I have broken dhclient. I can't get ip address from my ISP DHCP server.
However Ubuntu gets IP from my dlink router. 
Static configuration works perfect anyway. Future investigation gave my information that dhclient sends dhcpdiscover packages with incorrect checksum.
The same problem are here on another Ubuntu 18.04 PC with 2 different NICs.

[There is Wireshark file where first 3 packages are from liveCD,
and another are from installed Ubuntu on the same PC](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgMr_Bo41hrNh4EkVS0PKkyPUd7Adw).

[This](https://snag.gy/1tfrDH.jpg) is wireshark screenshot.

[This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5r55n9M8KF/) is system info by the wireless-info script from Ubuntu-forums

[This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DJQYvD7zDb/) is dhcpdump on liveCD

[This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3Y9mcVcxN5/) is dhcpdump on installed Ubuntu 18.04 with updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1789333) this is kernel issue, try to manually update the kernel.
Work fine with next:

```
uname -r
4.15.18-041518-generic
```